# PDFlib bad font handle

Tags: php, pdf, pdflib

so I'm currently writing a PHP program with PDFlib and got the following error when generating the PDF:
"PDFlib exception occurred: [1434] info_textline: Option 'font' has bad font handle 0".

Here's the function in which the error occurs:

```
function createHeaderText(PDFlib $p, int $textStartLeft, int $fontMedium, int $fontRegular) {
    $y = 719;
    $x = $textStartLeft;

    $pageHeading = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing";
    $reference = "Referenzobjekt";

    $optlist = "font=" . $fontMedium .
        " fontsize=16" .
        " fillcolor=white" .
        " wordspacing=0";

    $infoHeight = $p->info_textline($pageHeading, 'objectheight', $optlist);
    $p->fit_textline($pageHeading, $x, $y,  $optlist);
    $y = $y - ($infoHeight + 11);

    $optlist = "font=" . $fontRegular .
        " fontsize=12" .
        " fillcolor=white" .
        " wordspacing=0";

    $infoHeight = $p->info_textline($pageHeading, 'objectheight', $optlist);
    $p->fit_textline($pageHeading, $x, $y, $optlist);
    return $y - ($infoHeight + 27.5);
}
```

And here's my font handle:

```
$fontMedium = $p->load_font('fonts/NotoSerif-Medium', 'unicode', 'embedding');
$fontRegular = $p->load_font('fonts/NotoSerif-Regular', 'unicode', 'embedding');
$fontItalic = $p->load_font('fonts/NotoSerif-Italic', 'unicode', 'embedding');
```

Maybe someone can help me with this, it would help me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must always check whether the font handle returned by `load_font()` is actually valid. In the PDFlib PHP binding you must check that the font handle returned by `load_font()` is non-zero. If it is zero, an error occurred and you must retrieve the error reason by calling `$p->get_errmsg()` to find out what went wrong.

An alternative for explicitly checking the handle is to set option `errorpolicy=exception` like this:

```
$p->set_option("errorpolicy=exception");
```

Then an error like the failure to load a font will cause an exception.

Now to the potential root cause of the problem: Probably the PHP process does not have access to the `fonts` directory, either because the current working directory of the PHP process is not the parent directory of the `fonts` directory where your Noto fonts are stored, or because of a permission problem.

In any case checking the return value of `load_font()` and retrieving the error message is a first step towards resolving the problem.

Comment: thank you very much! apparently php really did not have permission to access the folder in which I put the fonts, but I fixed this. I just had to put the fonts from "assets/fonts" into the parent folder "assets" and now it's working. 
Again thank you, your good explanation really helped me a lot!